# Unique ID with time()

Tags: php, time, uniqueidentifier

If I use:

```
$t = time();
echo $t;
```

This will output something like: `1319390934`

**I have two questions:**

1. This value can be used as unique id ?
2. how to generate from it a date?

I can't use `uniqid()`, because I need a value that can be used to order (recent).

Comment: Unique in what context? How are you using the ID? (`microtime()` is also typically used for unique ID's).

Comment: in this case a number that can't be repeated. like an unique index in sql.

Comment: Why not use a database auto-increment?

Comment: No, I mean, do you want to prevent collisions between rows *per user*, or rows *for all users*? Or some other condition? What do you need a unique ID *for*?

Comment: By the way uniqid is also ordered. It's just an encoded microtime, basically.

Comment: Why do they need to be ordered?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `time()` as mentioned will give you a sortable way to create unique IDs. Concatenating strings will also further randomize your desired result and still keep it sortable:

```
$uniqueId= time().'-'.mt_rand();
```

Comment: Yes make sure you at mt_rand, other wise two or more users could have the same unique id if they come at exactly the same time.

Answer (score 4):

1. Obviously this cannot be used as a "unique" id because, well, it's not unique during the duration of the same second.
2. Look into [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

If you want something that is advertised as a unique id *and* both can be sorted, you can use something like this that involves [`uniqid`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php):

```
$u = time().'-'.uniqid(true);
```

I 'm perhaps over-simplifying here, taking for granted that all values `time` is going to produce will have the same number of digits (so that a string sort would produce the same results as a [natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167928/what-is-natural-ordering-when-we-talk-about-sorting)). If you don't want to make this assumption, then you could consider

```
$u = sprintf("%010s-%s", time(), uniqid(true));
```

Comment: Since it's for a database, an `auto_increment` column paired with a `NOW()` column could also work, depending on the use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this code in an environment where you have a user account with a unique ID, you can append time() to their account ID to generate a unique ID.

You can turn time() back into a date string using:

```
$time = time();
echo 'The datestamp for (' . $time . ') is ' . date("Y-m-d", $time);
```

Of course the date format can be altered using any of PHP's date() format.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this:

```php
$id = microtime();
```