# How to sort in natural order with Ember.js SortableMixin?

Tags: javascript, sorting, ember.js, natural-sort

[Ember.SortableMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html)

[Natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167928/what-is-natural-ordering-when-we-talk-about-sorting)

Answer (score 3):

What I've done in my project, is to override the orderBy function of the mixin (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/sortable.js#L52) and replace the Ember.compare() with this natural sort algorithm: https://github.com/overset/javascript-natural-sort

```
orderBy: function (item1, item2) {
  var result = 0,
    sortProperties = this.get('sortProperties'),
    sortAscending = this.get('sortAscending');

  Ember.assert("you need to define `sortProperties`", !!sortProperties);

  sortProperties.forEach(function (propertyName) {
    if (result === 0) {
      naturalSort.insensitive = true;
      result = naturalSort(Ember.get(item1, propertyName), Ember.get(item2, propertyName));
      if ((result !== 0) && !sortAscending) {
        result = (-1) * result;
      }
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```

I made a PR in order to make easier to plug any sort function in the sortable mixin, but it was closed. See details here:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1216
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1562

Answer (score 2):

You have to define additional "natural" property

```
App.Group = DS.Model.extend                                  
  name: DS.attr 'string'                                             
  natural_name: ( ->                                                
    # Split string into numeric and non-numeric parts
    # and convert numeric parts to actual numbers
    # Sort by resulting array of strings and numbers
    @get('name').split(/([0-9]+)/g).map (str) =>                     
      if str.match(/[0-9]+/) then parseInt(str, 10) else str         
  ).property('name')    



App.GroupsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  sortProperties: ['natural_name']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the SortableMixin you can do it like this:

```
childrenSorted: function() {
  return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
    sortProperties: ['name'],
    content: this.get('model.children')
  });
}.property('model.children.@each.name')
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Ember Data 1.0 (and possibly before), you might want to use `Ember.computed.sort`:

http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_sort