# What class allows me to manipulate the index and value?

Tags: java, php, arrays

In PHP, I can change the index and value of arrays.

```
$array = array("foo" => 54);
```

So then

```
$array["foo"]
```

returns 54. How can I do this in Java?

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent of PHP's associative array is a `Map` in Java. Both share the *key-value* pair implementation with the most commonly used implementation being [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("foo", 54);

System.out.println(map.get("foo")); // displays 54
```

Other implementations exist such as `LinkedHashMap` which preserves insertion order and `TreeMap` which is sorted according to the [natural ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167928/what-is-natural-ordering-when-we-talk-about-sorting) of its keys.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) implementation to do exactly this:

```
Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
m.put("foo", 54);
m.get("foo"); // will yield 54
```