# Alphanumeric sorting/ordering from database

Tags: php, mysql

in database, it store values of A1, A2, A10, A12, A5, A8
but when i retrieve it out it show as below:-

A1, A10, A12, A2, A5, A8

is there a way to sort it correctly? like

A1, A2, A5, A8, A10, A12

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql about natural sort

Answer (score 5):

If the string always starts with a single alpha/numeric prefix then you can use

```
 SELECT no from my_table order by substring(no,1,1), substring(no,2)+0
```

[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74959/11)

In PHP you can sort once it's in a multidimensional array by using [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) returning the results of a [strnatcasecmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcasecmp.php) call on the fields.

```
usort($records, function($a, $b){return strnatcasecmp($a["fieldname"], $b["fieldname"]);});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is known as a [natural sort, or a natural order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167928/what-is-natural-ordering-when-we-talk-about-sorting).

MySQL doesn't have the built-in ability to do a natural sort.
There's various options listed in response to this question: [Natural Sort in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql) ...but nothing that easily does what you want.

What you can do though, is get all the data back to PHP, and do the sorting there using the [`natsort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) function.

```
$vals = array('A1', 'A10', 'A12', 'A2', 'A5', 'A8');
natsort($vals);
print_r($vals); // A1, A2, A5, A8, A10, A12
```

This just sorts single values - but if you need to sort entire rows, you get the same functionality by using [`usort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with the [`strnatcmp()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php) function

Note that this requires you to fetch **all** the rows in order to sort them - any limiting or paging must be done after the sort in PHP, which can quickly become inefficient with large datasets.

Comment: Works well, but beware that that stops you from using `LIMIT` on the sort. You really need to fetch _all_ data to sort it.

Answer (score 1):

if the prefixes are always similar, you could maybe order by length first?

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(column), column
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [thumb] => oiuy
        )

    [1a] => Array
        (
            [thumb] => asdf
        )

    [1b] => Array
        (
            [thumb] => 2345
        )
)

uksort($array, function($a, $b) {

    sscanf($a, '%d%s', $an, $as);
    sscanf($b, '%d%s', $bn, $bs);

    if($an == $bn)
        return strcmp($as, $bs);

    return $an - $bn;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [natsort()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_natsort.asp). This works perfect with alphanumeric values.