# Sorting contents in file

Tags: python, sorting

My file contains  about 1602 elements like

```
 1ajith   
3abhiram  
9bijo   
2aaliya   
 etc..
```

I want to sort it. My desired output is:

```
1ajith  
2aaliya   
3abhiram    
9bijo
```

Plz help me with your valuable ideas.

Comment: Do you want to use [natural sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167928/what-is-natural-ordering-when-we-talk-about-sorting) or simple lexicographical sort?

Comment: Have you tried `sort input` from the command line?

Comment: Try to see some of the _related questions_ on the right.

Comment: What steps have you thus far tried?

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
ins = open( "file.txt", "r" )
array = []
for line in ins:
    array.append( line )
ins.close()
array = sorted(array)
for line in array :
    print line
```