# Sort multi-dimensional array - keep values of keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date, key

I want to sort my array based on the key (which is a date) - preferrably both ASC and DESC.

I have tried to use several of the methods on SO, but keep getting bad results - so I thought I would ask the question again.

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [2015-05-29] => Array
        (
            [a] => 13
            [b] => 1
            [c] => 12
        )

    [2015-05-28] => Array
        (
            [a] => 10
            [b] => 1
            [c] => 1
        )

    [2015-05-27] => Array
        (
            [a] => 2
        )

    [2015-05-30] => Array
        (
            [b] => 24
            [c] => 25
        )

)
```

I use this function - which should work according to several posts:

```
uasort($days, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['points'] - $b['points'];
});
```

But it doesn't, as the array gets returned like this:

```
    Array
    (
        [2015-05-30] => Array
            (
                [b] => 24
                [c] => 25
            )

        [2015-05-27] => Array
            (
                [a] => 2
            )

        [2015-05-28] => Array
            (
                [a] => 10
                [b] => 1
                [c] => 1
            )

        [2015-05-29] => Array
            (
                [a] => 13
                [b] => 1
                [c] => 12
            )

    )
```

I want to have the array returned like this:

```
   Array
(
    [2015-05-27] => Array
        (
            [a] => 2
        )

    [2015-05-28] => Array
        (
            [a] => 10
            [b] => 1
            [c] => 1
        )

    [2015-05-29] => Array
        (
            [a] => 13
            [b] => 1
            [c] => 12
        )

    [2015-05-30] => Array
        (
            [b] => 24
            [c] => 25
        )

)
```

**or in reverse order!**

Who can help me solve this problem?

Comment: 1) Post your expected output. 2) Post your original array. 3) Can't find `$a['points']` within array ? What does it means really?

Comment: @taapo You might want to sort using a natural order, take a look at the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php and an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167928/what-is-natural-ordering-when-we-talk-about-sorting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any own sorting function. Just use [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)/[`krsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php), .e.g.

```
//ASC         //DESC
ksort($arr);  //krsort($arr);
```

Comment: Yep this'll work for him if OP is only in need of sorting the keys consisting date

Comment: @Uchiha As I read the question this is what OP wants and with the added expected output `ksort()` is what he's looking for

Comment: @Rizier, i doubt this would work, it will give hime the same result that he has posted