# How can i sort array by name?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to sort it be the number of the names of each file.
The array content is:

```
0Infrared.jpg
10Infrared.jpg
12Infrared.jpg
14Infrared.jpg
16Infrared.jpg
2Infrared.jpg
4Infrared.jpg
6Infrared.jpg
8Infrared.jpg
```

But i want it to be ordered like it is on the hard disk:

```
0Infrared.jpg
2Infrared.jpg
4Infrared.jpg
6Infrared.jpg
8Infrared.jpg
10Infrared.jpg
12Infrared.jpg
14Infrared.jpg
16Infrared.jpg

string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(countriesMainPath + "\\" + currentDownloadCountry,
             "*infrared*.jpg");
                            Array.Sort(list, (x, y) => String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
```

The variables x and y does not have the properties Name

Comment: If you have a fixed pattern `NNNInfrared.jpg` then you can remove the `Infrared.jpg` part and then parse to int and sort by that number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extract the number, parse it and sort the entire list by this number

```
string[] sorted = list.Select(x => new { 
           Item = x, 
           Number = int.Parse(Regex.Match(x, "[0-9]+").Value) })
               .OrderBy(x => x.Number).Select(x => x.Item).ToArray();
```

Note that this solution assumes that all files start with a number.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a strongly typed collection, like array of FileInfo, you could use [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327(v=vs.110).aspx) or similar overload to retrieve such a collection

[FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) has a name property which you can use in your comparer

The type of sorting that you're doing is called a [natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167928/what-is-natural-ordering-when-we-talk-about-sorting)