# Finding the key corresponding to the maximum value in a hash map

Tags: java, hashmap, max

I'm trying to find the key corresponding to the maximum value in a HashMap. My declaration is as follows:

```
HashMap<Node, Double> coinD= new HashMap<>();
```

However, when I try to use an anonymous function to compare two values inside the entrySet of this map, I get a type casting error:

```
Node bestNode = Collections.max(coinD.entrySet(), (e1, e2) -> e1.getValue() - e2.getValue()).getKey();
```

Returns a type mismatch on e1.getValue() and e2.getValue(): cannot convert from double to int. Where is this coming from? Why is an integer necessary here; why can't the function use doubles to compare? Does the function I defined require ints, or does .getValue() have to return an int? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If your values are `Double`-typed, you can't use `d1-d2` because that returns a `double` which is not compatible with the `int` return type of `Comparator.compare`. Try `.max(coinD.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue())` or `.max(coinD.entrySet(), (e1,e2)->Double.compare(e1,e2))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to pass a lambda that should implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) as an argument to `max`, but `Comparable` **must** return an `int`, while you are producing a `double` as the result of subtracting a double from another.

You can fix this easily by using `Double.compare(e1.getValue(), e2.getValue())` instead of subtracting both values:

```
 Node bestNode = Collections.max(coinD.entrySet(), 
        (e1, e2) -> Double.compare(e1.getValue(), e2.getValue())).getKey();
```

[@ernest_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5761558/ernest-k) also has a good point: if the values of your map are have a natural sort order, and you want to use that order, [Map.Entry.comparingByValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue) yields slightly shorter code:

```
 Node bestNode = Collections.max(coinD.entrySet(), 
        (e1, e2) -> Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer- just to clarify, what would a "natural sort order" constitute?

Comment: @rjc810 - take a look at [What is natural ordering when we talk about sorting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167928/what-is-natural-ordering-when-we-talk-about-sorting) - that may help.